# Collision and response between sprites?

Tags: sprites, collision-detection

What is an easy way to have sprites collide and react to the collision? E.g. if I'm writing a game in XNA or with Canvas 2D and need to write the code myself very simply.

Answer (score 7):

The XNA collision series is very thorough for 2D collisions, covering collisions between bounding boxes, heightmaps, and per pixel collsion. The sample is for XNA but the concepts can be transferred elsewhere.

http://creators.xna.com/en-US/tutorial/collision2drectangle

Comment: The above link still works, but since XNA Creator's Club is now App Hub, here's the direct link so you don't have to wait for it to redirect you: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_rectangle